# How to download installed Jenkins plugins (as .hpi/.jpi files) to local storage?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

As part of security compliance, we need to scan all the plugins that are installed in multiple Jenkins instances. For scanning the hpi/jpi plugin files, we need them in local storage. Is there a way to download plugin files from a Jenkins instance to a desired storage location? Copying from plugins directory is not an option because we don't have server level access to all Jenkins servers.

Comment: You can get the list of installed plugins (and ver) from the system info page and then just `wget`  a copy from the jenkins plugins site.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jenkins plugin manager

```
java -jar /tmp/jenkins/jenkins-plugin-manager-*.*.jar --war /tmp/jenkins/jenkins.war --plugin-download-directory <DESTINATION_DIR>/plugins --plugins PLUGIN_NAME:PLUGIN_VERSION PLUGIN_NAME:PLUGIN_VERSION
```

Refer to https://github.com/jenkinsci/plugin-installation-manager-tool for more details